# Can we securely serve content (video/images) if player is HTML5?

Tags: html, html5-video, html5-audio

I have a custom multi-media player written in silverlight which displays both images and video. As you can guess, lot of people do not have silverlight and want us to use a better tech.

I am keen on HTML5, but then few concerns:

1. How do i avoid users to download content to their local machines? I just want them to stream from servers when they want to view it.
2. How do i avoid users to copy paste all the player code, as its just HTML/JS?
3. Is there a way we can do adaptive streaming in HTML5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers to your concerns are:

1. You can't
2. You can't
3. If you mean like RTMP, there's no support currently

If these are your primary concerns, then HTML5 video is not the solution you are looking for.  You may find [this mailing list thread interesting](http://lists.whatwg.org/pipermail/help-whatwg.org/2011-February/000743.html), just one of many times the issue has been raised but with some nice long explanations.

Comment: Word. In short, if you don’t want users to be able to have content on their local machines, don’t put it on the web.

Comment: This about sums it up, but see http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/06/flash-and-html5-tag.html for YouTube's take on why HTML5 can't replace Flash (yet)